# 'method-wrapper' object is not iterable in AES CTR pycrypto library

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I'm trying to implement an encryption/decryption function in python2.
This is the encryption scheme:
[image: encryption scheme] However, I'm getting a `'method-wrapper' object is not iterable` error in the AES CTR function of the pycrypto library

This is the stacktrace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1c44f21fcf83> in <module>()
     45         l = random.randint(16,48)
     46         m = random_bytes(l)
---> 47         assert specialDecryption(k, specialEncryption(k, m)) == m

<ipython-input-5-1c44f21fcf83> in specialEncryption(k, m)
      7     # compute PRF
      8     r = random_bytes(KEYLENGTH/8)
----> 9     prf = lengthQuadruplingPRF(k, r)
     10 
     11     # xor

<ipython-input-4-59fb6141461b> in lengthQuadruplingPRF(k, r)
     34     assert len(k) == KEYLENGTH/8
     35     assert len(r) <= KEYLENGTH/8
---> 36     obj = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=make_counter())
     37     output = obj.encrypt(r*4)
     38     return output

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.pyc in new(key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
    204 
    205     kwargs["add_aes_modes"] = True
--> 206     return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
    207 
    208 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.pyc in _create_cipher(factory, key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
     77             raise TypeError("IV is not meaningful for the ECB mode")
     78 
---> 79     return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ctr.pyc in _create_ctr_cipher(factory, **kwargs)
    323     # 'counter' used to be a callable object, but now it is
    324     # just a dictionary for backward compatibility.
--> 325     _counter = dict(counter)
    326     try:
    327         counter_len = _counter.pop("counter_len")

TypeError: 'method-wrapper' object is not iterable
```

Here's the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = os.urandom(KEYLENGTH/8)  # generate key
    l = random.randint(16,48)
    m = os.urandom(l)
    c = specialEncryption(k, m) ## FIRST IN THE FAILURE STACK

def specialEncryption(k, m):     
   ... other code

    # compute PRF
    r = os.urandom(KEYLENGTH/8)
    prf = lengthQuadruplingPRF(k, r) ## SECOND IN THE FAIL STACK

    ... other code

def make_counter():
    import struct
    def gen():
        i = 0;
        while True:
            yield struct.pack('>QQ', 0, i)
            i += 1
    return gen().next

def lengthQuadruplingPRF(k, r):
    # Input: 16 byte key, 16 byte value
    # Output: 64 byte pseudorandom bytes
    obj = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=make_counter()) ## FAILS HERE
    output = obj.encrypt(r*4)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `counter` should be an iterable capable of initializing a `dict`, not a bound method.

I suspect changing your `make_counter` function to:

```
return gen()
```

from:

```
return gen().next
```

is enough to fix it.

Comment: Now I get `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 16; 2 is required`

Comment: @Kek: Ah, yeah, looks like you packed it down to an iterator of 16 byte long sequences for some reason. What is the intent here? I'm not even sure why you think you need to pass this sequence.

Comment: Ah, hey, just read the docs. I'd suggest trying the recommended `Crypto.Util.Counter` here; I'm guessing the API has changed in different releases. https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Util.Counter-module.html